# Using Entity Framework in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a web portal on real estate. I am building it on ASP.NET MVC 5. For database connectivity, should I use Entity framework or not? and why? If not then what should I use? (I was using normal sqlclient method when I was working on web forms).

Updating for more clarity :
I am having very complex query scenarios in my project such as I have to search n various filters etc. I am also using angular ajax for many features. Now can anyone suggest either go with EF or not?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ORM (like Entity Framework) because it will read data from a database and give you back some easy to use classes, manage change tracking, allow easy updates, etc, etc. These two articles may help as they list of ORMs and contain some performance data:

[Fetch performance of various .NET ORM / Data-access frameworks](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/fetch-performance-of-various-net-orm-data-access-frameworks)

[Fetch performance of various .NET ORM / Data-access frameworks, part 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/fetch-performance-of-various-net-orm-data-access-frameworks-part-2)

Also you may want to take a look at this Stackoverflow question:

[Are there good reasons not to use an ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194147/are-there-good-reasons-not-to-use-an-orm)

Answer (score 0):

There are several infrastructures designed to help you create websites using ASP.NET. The EntityFramework, which is part of [ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), help you do [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), MVC 5 is, well, for MVC. There are others, like [Razor](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_intro.asp).

All in all, it seems fine to use EF for DB connectivity and ORM, as it seems to be the standard.

Comment: Thanks , I am having complex queries for search n all, in all these cases, the EF will be effective or I should go with ADO.NET

Comment: OK, then I suggest you edit your question so that is more clear.